# show 3 items on owl carousel mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

This is my site that im working on
http://coreinfonet.com/mock/index.html

I am trying to get it to display like this in mobile (3 items)
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/center.html

i have been trying to tweak both the css and js but couldn't get it working. Not sure if im tweaking the right thing.
(im not a programmer, just copying codes from here and there)

I've search through the previous posting but couldn't find the any reference that can help. Hope you guys can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Owl carousel v2. I do not know exactly what your problem is, but you can try Owl carousel v1 (https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel)

I tried v2 some weeks ago, it seems like there is a bug.